# edit link shifted after pressing search button in grid view C# win form

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I load my data in grid view. At loading time, the edit link is at the right most end of the grid view i.e. the last column of the grid view.

In this grid view, I've feature of searching with multiple fields input. 
When I press **search** the edit link appears as the first column of the grid view.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Library.UI
{
    public partial class ReceiptReport : Form
    {
        private bool isSearchMode = false;
        private bool isEditMode = false;

        public ReceiptReport()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            isSearchMode = false;
            GetReceipt(isSearchMode);
            edit();
        }

        private void ReceiptReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            dtpFrom.Value = DateTime.Today.AddDays(-1);
            isEditMode = false;
            FillPaymentMode();
            this.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
        }

        private void edit()
        {
            DataGridViewLinkColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            Editlink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
            Editlink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
            Editlink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            Editlink.Text = "Edit";
            receiptGrid.Columns.Add(Editlink);
        }

        private void receiptGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            int paymentTxnId_ = 0;
            try
            {
                if (e.RowIndex >= 0 && receiptGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 0)
                {
                    DataRowView drv = receiptGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem as DataRowView;
                    paymentTxnId_ = Convert.ToInt32(drv.Row["paymentTxnId"]);
                    Receipt receiptFrm = new Receipt(paymentTxnId_);
                    receiptFrm.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent;
                    receiptFrm.Show();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                string title = "Error";
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), title);
            }
        }

        private void GetReceipt(bool mode)
        {
            int dummyId = 0;
            int getPaymentMode = 0;
            string fromDate = string.Empty;
            string toDate = string.Empty;
            string payPartyName = string.Empty;
            string recNum = string.Empty;

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            ReceiptDal objDal = new ReceiptDal();

            try
            {
                if (mode == false)
                {
                    dt = objDal.GetReceipt(dummyId);
                    receiptGrid.DataSource = dt;
                    receiptGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;                    
                }
                else
                {
                    receiptGrid.DataSource = null;
                    getPaymentMode = (int)cmbPaymentMode.SelectedValue;
                    fromDate = dtpFrom.Value.ToShortDateString();
                    toDate = dtpTo.Value.ToShortDateString();
                    payPartyName = txtPaymentPartyName.Text.Trim();
                    recNum = txtReceiptNum.Text.Trim();
                    dt = objDal.SearchReceipt(getPaymentMode, recNum, payPartyName, fromDate, toDate);
                    receiptGrid.DataSource = dt;
                    receiptGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                    if (isEditMode == false)
                    {
                        edit();
                        isEditMode = true;
                    }                    
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
            }
        }


        #region search

        private void btnSearch_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                ValidateDateTime(dtpFrom.Text, dtpTo.Text);
                isSearchMode = true;
                GetReceipt(isSearchMode);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
            }
        }
        #endregion       
    }
}
```

I can not find why is this happening? Please guide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

During `Form` construction, many aspects of a `DataGridView` control play by a different set of rules than they do afterwards. For example, the column indexing for data bound columns versus manually added columns.

**THE WHY**

Take, for example, your constructor and some mocked columns:

> ```
> public ReceiptReport()
> {
>     InitializeComponent();
>     isSearchMode = false;
>     GetReceipt(isSearchMode); // Adds N columns. ex. | Id | Name | Gender |
>     edit();                   // Adds link column.   | Id | Name | Gender | Edit |
> }
> ```

After `GetReceipt` is run, the `DataGridView` will have N columns, temporarily indexed 0 to N-1, with column 0 hidden. After `edit` is run, your `DataGridView` should have N+1 columns, but here's where things get hairy. By the order they were added, you'll visually see the link column as the last. However, bindings don't occur until the constructor has finished running. Therefore, even though you may visually see the columns ordered like (ex.):

```
/*Hidden*/
|   Id   |  Name  | Gender |  Edit  |
```

Their column index is as follows:

```
|   1    |   2    |   3    |   0    |
```

Hence, the reason in `CellContentClick` that you made this condition:

> ```
> receiptGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Index == 0 // Trigger when link column's clicked.
> ```

However, if you were to move that same code from the constructor into the beginning of your `Form.Load` handler, the columns would still visually render the same but the indexing would now be as follows:

```
|   0    |   1    |   2    |   4    |
```

With that messy default behavior in place, what happens when you click `Search`? `GetReceipt` is called and the following code runs:

> ```
> receiptGrid.DataSource = null; // Remove bound columns. | Edit |
> // ...
> receiptGrid.DataSource = dt;   // Re-add bound columns. | Edit | Id | Name | Gender |
> receiptGrid.Columns[0].Visible = false;                 /*Hide*/
> if (isEditMode == false)
> {
>     edit();                    // Re-add edit column.   | Edit | Id | Name | Gender | Edit |
>     isEditMode = true;
> }
> ```

Visually this results as follows:

```
/*Hidden*/
|  Edit  |   Id   |  Name  | Gender |  Edit  |
```

Consequently, there are 2 `Edit` columns. The first one should be hidden, although your OP states that you see it, so I'm guessing there's some additional attempts and carry over of code into your question. Additionally, the visible `Edit` column (NOT index 0) will not trigger the code within the `CellContentClick` condition. This should explain the behavior your were asking about [in your other question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31395215/3773066).

**THE FIX**

```
private void edit()
{
  DataGridViewLinkColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
  Editlink.Name = "Edit"; // ADD
  // ...
}

private void GetReceipt(bool mode)
{
  // ...

  try
  {
    if (mode == false)
      // ...
    else
    {
      this.dataGridView1.DataSource = null;
      this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear(); // ADD
      // ...
    }
  }
  // ...
}

private void receiptGrid_CellContentClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    // ...
        if (receiptGrid.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "Edit") // CHANGE
    // ...
}
```

Since the `Edit` column `Index` can vary, we'll check for it by `Name` instead. And since you are re-adding it to `DataGridView.Columns`, we want to remove the old one.

Comment: Thanks for this clear explanation. I think my approach of doing this is wrong. I tried to search in internet for the same but can not find examples. Is there any other way of the same thing properly. Please suggest.

Comment: *Is there any other way*? I would say certainly - that's the beauty of programming IMHO. *Properly*? Maybe. But only you know the full extent of what you're trying to accomplish here. As far as I can tell, what you're doing should work just fine with those few fixes. It may not always be pretty, but sometimes that's just the kind of thing we have to do to overcome some of the DataGridView's odd behaviors.

Comment: Thanks for your helpful reply and comments. I really appreciated your help. Thanks!!!