# Datagrid view in Windows Form C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview, datagrid

Hello I am using Datagridview in C# windows form , In data grid View I am using Data grid Link columns, example code is here

```
  DataGridViewLinkColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            Editlink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
            Editlink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
            Editlink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            Editlink.Text = "Edit";
            gvJobs.Columns.Add(Editlink);
```

and it gives me output [image]

its fine but When I reload the grid it gives doesnot remove the existing edit column by giving data source null. Example Code and output is here.

```
 gvJobs.DataSource = null;
            var jobs = (from v in General.ent.Jobs
                        where (v.MRNumber == (string)txtMrNumber.Text)
                        select new
                        {
                            MRNumber = v.MRNumber,
                            NumberOfDocuments = v.noofdocuments,
                            PageNumbers = v.PageNumbers,
                            JobStatus = v.job_status,
                            ScannerType = v.scanner_type,
                            DocumentType = v.Documenttype.document_name,
                            CreatedDate = v.received_date

                        }).ToList();
            gvJobs.DataSource = jobs;
            DataGridViewLinkColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
            Editlink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
            Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
            Editlink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
            Editlink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
            Editlink.Text = "Edit";
            gvJobs.Columns.Add(Editlink);
```

and output [image]

I want Image 1 output after reloading the grid.

Comment: possible duplicate of [edit link shifted after pressing search button in grid view C# win form](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31454431/edit-link-shifted-after-pressing-search-button-in-grid-view-c-sharp-win-form)

Comment: Automatic datacolumn generation will ways add the genrated columns to the end.. You should remove the link column you added before resetting the datasource and then add it again.

Comment: After `gvJobs.DataSource = null;` add the line `gvJobs.Columns.Clear();`. For an explanation, see the question I linked above..

Comment: It's enough to add the column *once*. You're adding it now *whenever you load data*. This of course adds the `Edit` column over and over. I suggest you add the column in your form's constructor and then just do the data binding. I also suggest you don't use auto generated columns at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
gvJobs.Columns.Clear();
```

is worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

You will either have to remove the column while reloading your grid or avoid adding the column to the grid while reloading it.

You could use

```
gvJobs.Columns.Remove()
```

inorder to remove the Edit Column

or

```
for (int j=0;j<gvJobs.Columns.Count ;j++)
{
    if (gvJobs.Columns[j].HeaderText == "Edit")
    {    
         DataGridViewLinkColumn Editlink = new DataGridViewLinkColumn();
         Editlink.UseColumnTextForLinkValue = true;
         Editlink.HeaderText = "Edit";
         Editlink.DataPropertyName = "lnkColumn";
         Editlink.LinkBehavior = LinkBehavior.SystemDefault;
         Editlink.Text = "Edit";
         gvJobs.Columns.Add(Editlink);
     }


 }
```

I hope this helps you out.